# adsl modem with the most security features

Tags: network

I am looking for the adsl modem with the most security features available. A 'least likely to be compromised', can be configured to be hack proof adsl modem with an internal firewall and other security settings like stealth mode, udp session control, allow/block protocols and services etc. The more the better.

Suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to the site - please familiarise yourself with the [faq] - this question is offtopic and any answers would change over time. You'd be better off looking at sites that compare products.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a NAT/router, not a modem. Usually, modem is provided to you by your ISP and can also work in NAT/router mode, which is the default setting, but it can also work in bridged mode, meaning you can use your own router. So you are looking for a router. If you'd like flexibility and all the features you describe, I recommend installing PfSense on a cheap computer with 2 NICs. It is the cheapest way to get the most features out of a router. It costs about 50 kg of bread or less (older used computer).

Comment: We're pricing technology based on the mass of simple food products? Has the apocalypse started where you live? Is it zombies?